# is there a way to connect several iPad (client App) to a Central iPad (Server App) without internet connection?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bluetooth

I want to send data from client applications (ipad application client) to a Server application (ipad server application) without using an internet connection because there is no wireless router.

I believe I can Send data using bluetooth one device at a time
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: "Without Internet connection" and "no wireless router" is not even close to equivalent. You can connect them via Wi-Fi using a local network even if there's no access to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

This mammoth tutorial can guide you through using bluetooth http://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1